# Problem with Excel SQL query code when it reads a closed workbook

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Hi
I use the following code (part shown) which works great.
Basically I run a SQL query from excel which queries a closed workbook, extracts the info and puts it on the current opened sheet.

The problem is that one of the fields ("To") for some reason it always returns a value of nothing, even if every cell in that column has in fact information so I am not sure why it doesn't get the value.
All other columns are read perfectly. 
Anyway knows why and whether there are some formatting (or other) specifics which affects SQL queries of this type?. There are no errors...simply the value is always nothing.

```
    some code...
    objRecordset.Open "SELECT  * FROM [FILESAVED$] , objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
for next_row=1 to objRecordset.count
            Range("AF" & next_row) = objRecordset.Fields.Item("Validto")
            Range("AG" & next_row) = objRecordset.Fields.Item("To")
            Range("AO" & next_row) = objRecordset.Fields.Item("User Name")
objRecordset.movenext
next next_row
    ...more code
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do have error handling on?  If so, make sure there really is a field named "To" and not To with a space, or other non-printable, character after it.  It should throw an error, but not if error handling is turned on.

Comment: Can you access the value using the Field's index instead of the name?

Comment: Yes, I tried using index instead of name..same problem...:(

Comment: Dick, yes I checked for spaces...but no problems there. There are no errors, that's the strange part...I just don't get any values...

Comment: Have you tried updating your SQL to include the actual field names instead of using "select * " ?  That might give you some information.

Comment: yes I did, however it appears that you can't do 'by field' queries when you use Excel SQL...SELECT field1,field2,field3 etc gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of data is in the column?  When you treat an Excel workbook as a database table, Excel infers the column type by matching it to whatever it infers about the majority of entries.  (So if 60% look like numbers and 40% like text, it will treat them all as numbers.)  This can cause errors, though it doesn't precisely match what you describe.

Comment: Values in the "problem column" are mainly dates, however some data is incorrectly formatted, so I am probably ending with several types of data, just like you say.
I did think this might be the problem however it doesn't make sense that I don't get any value....why should the code care if the type is different between records ? It should at least show something.